# Problem in reading text file into array in csh

Tags: csh

I have a text file that looks like this -

```
1 29 12
1 22 17
1 20 43
1 48 30
1 3 0
1 21 25
1 18 9
1 14 1
1 44 45
1 52 26
1 NaN 27
1 13 46
1 5 37
1 34 23
1 39 40
```

whose columns I want to store into different array variables. I have used the following command -

```
#!/bin/csh
set Logfile=$proj_path/data/individual/AAR"$subj"/activation/trialWise/"AAR"$subj"_PseudoOrder.txt"

set acc_full= (`awk -F' ' '{print $1}' "$Logfile"`)

set stim1= (`awk -F' ' '{print $2}' "$Logfile"`)

set stim2= (`awk -F' ' '{print $3}' "$Logfile"`)
```

The problem is that the 3rd awk command only stores the last number in the 3rd column.

Comment: Have you consider changing the shell? https://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file has windows line endings. You must have edited on a Windows machine at some point. This means there are trailing `\r` characters which are part of your `csh` variables, so that when you print the variable's value, the `\r` cause the previous values to be overwritten:

```
$ printf 'a\rb\rc\re\r\n'
e
$ printf 'a\rb\rc\re\r\n' | od -c
0000000   a  \r   b  \r   c  \r   e  \r  \n
0000011
```

You can use one of these commands to fix your file and after that your script will work (although you should really think about whether you want to use `csh` as a scripting language: [it is a very, very bad choice for scripting](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html)):

```
dos2unix foo_PseudoOrder.txt
```

or (assuming GNU `sed` or compatible)

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' foo_PseudoOrder.txt
```

or

```
tr -d '\r' < foo_PseudoOrder.txt > tmpFile && mv tmpFile foo_PseudoOrder.txt
```

Note that the `tr` solution above will delete *all* `\r` from the file, even if for some reason you have one that isn't at the end of the line and want to keep it.

Comment: Hello @terdon, Your third solution did the trick nicely.

About changing from csh to another language, I am working on a large set of Pre written codes, already in csh, so changing it now may need some rewriting on my Part, which I can't tackle at the moment.

Comment: @Stéphane, what GNUism did I use there, is it the `\r` that isn't understood by all seds?

Comment: @SanjanaHari yeah, that makes sense. My condolences then :)

Comment: @terdon, both `-i` and `\r`. On FreeBSD and derivatives, it's `-i ''` for in-place editing without backup. Might as well use `perl`: `perl -pi -e 's/\r$//' file`

Answer (score 2):

You have DOS line endings, see [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

The `-F ' '`s in your script are setting FS to the value it already has by default so don't do that as it's doing nothing useful.

If you have GNU awk (for multi-char RS) change this:

```
awk '{print $3}' "$Logfile"
```

to this:

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' '{print $3}' "$Logfile"
```

or with any awk:

```
awk '{sub(/\r$/,""); print $3}' "$Logfile"
```